# python - numpy - get index of matrix that contains True

Tags: python, numpy

In the following code

```
import numpy as np

np.array([
    [False,  True, False],
    [False, False, False],
    [False, False,  True],
    [False, False, False]
])
```

I want to get retrieve the array `[True, False, True, False]` corresponding to the lists that contain at least one True.

Comment: Check [`np.any`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.any.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, the best way to accomplish that is to use [np.any](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.any.html) which tests whether any element along a given axis evaluates to True. In practice:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([
           [False,  True, False],
           [False, False, False],
           [False, False,  True],
           [False, False, False]])

np.any(a, axis=1)
array([ True, False,  True, False])
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

You can use [np.any](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.any.html) which test whether any array element along a given axis evaluates to `True`.

```
result = np.any(arr, axis=1)
```

**OR,**

You can use [`np.sum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) to sum all the values along the column axis and compare these values if they are greater than or equal to 1 which returns a boolean mask.

```
result = (np.sum(arr, axis=1) >= 1)
```

**Result:**

```
[True False  True False]
```